# Importar varios archivos csv a R, sin perder su nombre original

Tags: r, csv, rstudio

Estoy teniendo un problema ( espero que simple) en cuanto a la importación de múltiples archivos a R.

Mi idea es importar muchos csv y luego generar un df con todos los datos, esta parte la tengo resuelta.
El problema es que necesito que cada csv que importe tenga su nombre en una columna para no perder el rastro del mismo.

Esto es lo que tengo y me funciona bien, pero al crear el df final, pierdo el seguimiento de la fecha de cada csv que me une al dataframe final.

```
lista.archivos<- list.files(path="F:/RODRIGO/Lid/Lid_proyect/Archivos", pattern="*.csv")


df.list <- lapply(lista.archivos, read.csv)
df.final <- do.call("rbind", df.list)
```

Me gustaría crear antes de la unión, una columna que sea el nombre de mi archivo ya que tengo la fecha en la cual se tomo esos datos. Esa fecha esta presente en el nombre de mi csv. Tendré que hacer un bucle for?

processed_02_B_**20191350**_V002.csv (Nombre de mis csv con la fecha de la colecta de los datos)
No se si eso es posible o tendré que hacerlo a mano previamente en cada csv.

Gracias un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es bastan sencilla la solución, lo que falta inicialmente en la lista es ponerle un nombre a cada elemento:

```
names(df.list) <- lista.archivos
```

Ahora cada elemento tendrá el nombre del archivo y cuando hagas `df.final <- do.call("rbind", df.list)`, ese nombre será parte del `rowname` de cada fila, si eventualmente lo quieres como un nombre de columna:

```
df.final$archivo <- rownames(df.final)
rownames(df.final) <- NULL
```

También, un poco más sencillo, es leer los `csv` mediante `sapply()` que ya se toma el trabajo de nombrar los elementos de la lista:

```
df.list <- sapply(lista.archivos, read.csv)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Patricio Moracho, me sirvió para lo que necesitaba, pero una consulta mas, existe alguna forma de cargar los archivos a R y que queden de forma individual en el environment? Sin aparecer como lista y luego unirse. Simplemente si tengo 10 csv, cargar los 10 con su nombre. Espero que me hayas entendido.

Comment: Si hay forma, te aclaro que no es lo mejor, manejar todo desde una lista es la forma natural. Si quieres que cada archivo se traduzca en una variable distinta, puedes usar `assign()`

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias, lo probaré. Saludos